# Correlation of beta coefficients from linear regression

Tags: regression, correlation

Suppose that I have a linear regression: $ y = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{2} + \epsilon $

I would like to demonstrate that one regression coefficients is significantly greater than the other: 
$H_{0} = \beta_{1} > \beta_{2}$ or $H_{0} = \beta_{1} - \beta_{2} > 0$.

Therefore, I would conduct a t-test:

$t = \mu_{d} / \sigma_{d} $ 
with $\mu_{d} = \beta_{1} - \beta_{2} $
and $\sigma_{d} =  \sqrt{\sigma_{\beta_{1}}^2 + \sigma_{\beta_{2}}^2 - Cov(\beta_{1}, \beta_{2})}$

and $Cov (\beta_{1}, \beta_{2}) = \sigma_{\beta_{1}} * \sigma_{\beta_{2}} * \rho_{\beta_{1}, \beta_{2}} $

As $\beta_{1}$, $\beta_{2}$, $\sigma_{\beta_{1}}$ and $\sigma_{\beta_{2}}$ are known from the regression results, the only mising part is the correlation of $\beta_{1}$ and $\beta_{2}$. However, I don't know how this can be computed and would be really thankful for any help!

Comment: Hi: You can calculate the covariance matrix $\Sigma  = \sigma^2 (X^{\prime}X)^{-1}$. The correlation is then the square root of the element in the second row and the third column.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: no problem. glad to help.